# New page after defined number of bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using `biblatex` with the `biber`-backend. Is there a possibility, to limit the number of items listed in the bibliography to a given number per page? E.g., I want to have a new page after 10 bibliography items.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way of doing this that should work for most setups is the following.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcounter{bibitemcount}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \ifbibliography
    {\stepcounter{bibitemcount}%
     \ifnumless{\value{bibitemcount}}{10}
       {}
       {\newpage
        \setcounter{bibitemcount}{0}}}
    {}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It may, however, be a bit nicer to add the code to start a new page in the bibliography environment. That is style dependent, so less portable. The example below is for `style=numeric`. The original `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` for that style can be found in [`numeric.bbx` (ll. 20-33 in biblatex v3.15a)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/e5d6e69e61613cc33ab1fcc2083a8277eb9cfce5/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx#L20-L33).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcounter{bibitemcount}


\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\stepcounter{bibitemcount}%
      \ifnumless{\value{bibitemcount}}{11}
        {}
        {\newpage
         \setcounter{bibitemcount}{0}}%
   \item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```